# How to change the "BaseMap" property of a shader from script? - Universal RP Template

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used to change the `BaseMap` texture using the standard 3D project in unity as follows:

```
[SerializeField] private Texture texture;

void Start()
{
    this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
}
```

However, the same code doesn't seem to work using the `Universal RP Template`. When I checked the shader properties, it shows that the `BaseMap` property is obsolete as shown in the picture below:

[image: Shader Obsolete Properties]

But when I drag and drop the texture at run time to the `BaseMap`, it works. I guess that means that it should work. (Below Pic):

[image: BaseMap Texture change at runtime]

My **MAIN** question now is, how do I change the `BaseMap` texture from script in `Universal RP Template`?

and is there other properties I should call and change their texture other than the `BaseMap` since it's written on the shader that the `BaseMap` is "ObsoletProperties"?

Comment: Btw "_MainTex" is obsolte because now its called "_BaseMap", see my answer for fix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update, this should do the trick:**

```
[SerializeField] private Texture texture;

void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_BaseMap", texture);
}
```

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Assign a  texture in the material editor, then change my code to this, `texture = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetTexture("_MainTex");` is it read it correctly?

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Also check this code: `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_BaseMap, texture");`

Comment: But how can I change the color option beside the texture ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Renderer m_Renderer;
public Texture m_MainTexture;

 void Start () {
        m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        m_Renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", m_MainTexture);
               }
```

Comment: `m_Renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", m_MainTexture );` is the same as using `m_Renderer.material.mainTexture = m_MainTexture;`